# How can I combine two separate scripts being piped together to make one script instead of two?

Tags: bash, shell, ffmpeg, youtube-dl

I have two scripts that I pipe together. `script1.sh | script2.sh` Originally they were part of the same but I could never make it work correctly. The last part of script1 calls on `youtube-dl` to read a batch file and outputs a list urls into the terminal. Note the trailing `-` allows youtube-dl to read from stdin.

```
 cat $HOME/file2.txt | youtube-dl --ignore-config -iga -
```

And script2 begins with:

```
while read -r input
do
ffmpeg [arg] [input] [arg2] [output]
```

What am I not seeing that is causing the script to hang when the two halves are combined yet work if one is piped into the other?

EDIT - It's kind of funny how the answer is in the question.. Live and learn.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The short answer is that a `|` is needed to make the scripts work together. In the question above I originally had a script that ended like this:

```
cat $HOME/file2.txt | youtube-dl --ignore-config -iga - 
while read -r input
do
ffmpeg [arg] [input] [arg2] [output]
```

But this does not work. We need to pipe into the `while` loop:

```
cat "$HOME/file2.txt" | youtube-dl --ignore-config -iga - | while read -r input
```

But we get the same results in a more efficient manner by doing this instead:

```
youtube-dl --ignore-config -iga "$HOME/file2.txt" | while read -r input
```

or if you rather:

```
youtube-dl --ignore-config -iga "$HOME/file2.txt" | \
while read -r input
```

Answer (score 1):

I probably would use something like this (line by line processing):

```
#!/usr/bin/bash
inputFile="$HOME/file2.txt"
while read -r line
do
    youtubeResult=$(youtube-dl --ignore-config -iga - "$line")
    ffmpeg [arg] "$youtubeResult" [arg2] [output]
done < "$inputFile"
```

Comment: @RanyAlbegWein Do you mean youtubeResult assignment, no? I have updated the answer.

Comment: You have spaces before and after the assignment operator.

Comment: @RanyAlbegWein Thanks, I haven't noticed this.

Comment: @tripleee Thank you for this useful website.